# model fit (r2) for glmmTMB

Tags: r, mixed-model, beta-distribution

I am having a really hard time finding certain summary statistics when running a beta generalized linear mixed model using the glmmTMB function in R. I would like to report the model fit (r2) for both the full model(random + fixed effects) and just the fixed effects as well as the x2 statistic for each fixed effect.

Comment: $1)$ What would you do if you were running your regressions without random effects? $2)$ What would you do for a linear mixed effects model?

Comment: I need to run a generalized linear mixed effects model. I have random effects that need to be included.

Comment: And if you were in either of the simpler situations I described…? // Moreover, you have true (observed) values and predictions, right? Why not just calculate the correlation between them like you would for the usual $R^2?$

Comment: If I was running a simple linear mixed effect model I would just use the rsq function from the package of the same name but this doesn't work for a model from the glmmTMB

Comment: But you know how to reuse the `cor` function, right?

Comment: Can you explain this better? I know I can calculate correlation coefficients with the cor function. But how can I do this with random effects? and after calculating the individual correlation coefficients do I just square them to get r2?

Comment: Your model can make predictions, right? I don’t offhand know the details of your particular software library, but doesn’t it give some function or method to predict from the models it fits?

Comment: Hey @Dave. If you don't know the answer, don't care to look it up and don't ask for clarification, it may be better not to comment. You seem to have more question than the OP does. It's confusing.

Comment: This is a difficult question because it's not even clear how to define $R^2$ for generalized LMM. It might be interesting to read the relevant section in the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-summaries-goodness-of-fit-decomposition-of-variance-etc.) by Ben Bolker.

Answer (score 1):

A useful pseudo r-squared is a version of Efron's pseudo r-squared   ([stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/)).

What's nice about this pseudo r-squared is that it can be determined for any model where it makes sense to investigate the difference between predicted values and actual values.  It's easy to calculate, and it's fairly easy to explain to an audience.

For the following example, I'll use a beta regression model from *glmmTMB*.  I used data from ([www.real-statistics.com/two-way-anova/scheirer-ray-hare-test/](http://www.real-statistics.com/two-way-anova/scheirer-ray-hare-test/)), but then converted the dependent variable to a proportion, and treated *Crop* as a random effect.

The *emmeans* package should support glmmTMB models ([cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html)).

I wrote a function in *rcompanion* package that will calculate Efron's pseudo r-squared, but it's easy to do manually as well.

```
if(!require(glmmTMB)){install.packages("glmmTMB")} 
if(!require(emmeans)){install.packages("emmeans")} 
if(!require(rcompanion)){install.packages("rcompanion")} 

Wheat = c(123,156,112,100,168,135,130,176,120,155,156,180,147,146,193)
Corn  = c(128,150,174,116,109,175,132,120,187,184,186,138,178,176,190)
Soy   = c(166,178,187,153,195,140,145,159,131,126,185,206,188,165,188)
Rice  = c(151,125,117,155,158,167,183,142,167,168,175,173,154,191,169)

Yield = c(Wheat, Corn, Soy, Rice) / 220

Fert  = factor(rep(c(rep("Blend X",5), rep("Blend Y",5), rep("Blend Z",5)),4))
Crop  = factor(c(rep("Wheat",15), rep("Corn",15), rep("Soy",15), rep("Rice",15)))

Real.stats = data.frame(Yield, Fert, Crop)

str(Real.stats)

library(glmmTMB)

model = glmmTMB(Yield ~ Fert + (1|Crop), data=Real.stats, family=beta_family())

summary(model)

library(emmeans)

joint_tests(model)

   ###  model term df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
   ###  Fert         2  55   8.304  0.0007

emmeans(model, ~ Fert, type="response")

   ### Fert    response     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
   ### Blend X    0.667 0.0266 55    0.612    0.718
   ### Blend Y    0.693 0.0260 55    0.638    0.742
   ### Blend Z    0.788 0.0221 55    0.740    0.829
   ### 
   ### Confidence level used: 0.95 
   ### Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale 

### Efron r-squared from rcompanion package

Actual    = Real.stats$Yield
Predicted = predict(model, type="response")
Residuals = residuals(model)

library(rcompanion)

efronRSquared(residual = Residuals, 
              predicted = Predicted, 
              statistic = "EfronRSquared")

   ### EfronRSquared 
   ###         0.282 

### Efron r-squared by manual calculation

pseudo_r_squared = 1 - sum((Actual - Predicted)^2)/sum((Actual - mean(Actual))^2)
pseudo_r_squared

   ### 0.2817981
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't resolved your issue you should be able to generate marginal and conditional r2 values using the performance package in R. Take a look at this thread for details - https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/169.

Answer (score 0):

The marginal (no random effects) and conditional (with random effects) can be estimated by predicting the responses for the fixed-only (marginal) and full (conditional) models, correlating to the response data points, and squaring.

Nakagawa, S., and Schielzeth, H. (2013). A general and simple method for obtaining R2 from generalized linear mixed-effects models. Methods in Ecology and Evolution, 4(2), 133–142. doi:10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x

Nakagawa, S., Johnson, P. C. D., and Schielzeth, H. (2017). The coefficient of determination R2 and intra-class correlation coefficient from generalized linear mixed-effects models revisited and expanded. Journal of The Royal Society Interface, 14(134), 20170213. doi:10.1098/rsif.2017.0213